# DVD Installation noapic error

Tags: boot, dvd, apic

Hi I'm trying ti install Ubuntu from DVD. I Boot from the DVD and it gets as far as a page of text with the error; "end kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work"
!Boot with apic=debug and sensd a report. Then try booting with the 'noapic' option.
All the answers to this error are for a system where ubuntu is already installed, I'm getting it when booting from the instalation DVD so not sure how to fix this.

Thanks
Mike

Update!!!! 
I found the little nugget of information which had been missing from all the other answers; 
Press any key when the screen with the little keyboard at the bottom appears to get to the boot menu!
I'd been pressing ESC & F6 at this screen and all the other function keys but it turns out it's just a regular key you need to press!

I was going to delete this post as I no longer need an answer but then thought this info might be useful to someoene else who's new to Ubuntu....

Thanks